# Split, sort and merge string

Tags: c#

How can I compare 2 strings in C# then split on a separator, merge (remove duplicates) and sort the items?

```
var str1 = "123ABC;789XYZ";
var str2 = "456CDE;123ABC;012ABC";

var result = str1.SplitSortAndMerge(str2); // => result = "012ABC;123ABC;456CDE;789XYZ"
```

Comment: How is `str1` related to `str2` and the result?

Comment: Could `str1` have more than one element? Could `str2` have duplicates in itself?

Comment: OK, I edited the question. The comparison is on 2 strings.

Comment: what do you mean by "Comparison"? What happens if `str1` is not in `str2`?

Comment: They are merged in the result (with duplicates removed) and sorted alphabetically.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should be help you.

```
var str2 = "456CDE;123ABC;012ABC";
var result = string.Join(";",str2.Split(new[]{";"},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Distinct().OrderBy(x=>x));
```

If you need to include str1, then

```
var str1 = "123ABC1";
var result = string.Join(";",str2.Split(new[]{";"},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Concat(new[]{str1}).Distinct().OrderBy(x=>x));
```

Based on your last update in OP, It would be better if you can write an extension method.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string SplitAndSort(this IEnumerable<string> source)
    {
        var list = source.Where(x=>x!=null)
                         .SelectMany(c=>c.Split(new[]{";"},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                         .Distinct()
                         .OrderBy(x=>x);
        return string.Join(";",list);
    }
}
```

Now you can use

```
var str1 = "123ABC1;012ABC";
var str2 = "456CDE;123ABC;123ABC;012ABC";
(new []{str1,str2}).SplitAndSort();
```

Output

```
   012ABC;123ABC;123ABC1;456CDE
```

Comment: OK, thank you. Then I just need to check that str1 and str2 are not null to avoid NRE.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Was actually doing precisely that when you commented, have updated answer :) Thanks

Comment: @AntoineGriffard Please check the Extension method. It takes care of nulls too.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str2 = "456CDE;123ABC;012ABC";
var result = string.Join(";",str2.Split(';').Distinct().OrderBy(x => x).ToList());
```